# Highcharts: show stack total in shared tooltip, via footerFormat property

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a stacked bar chart, with a shared tooltip, and I am trying to pull the stack total into the tooltip via the footerFormat property.

I thought this would be a simple property I could access, but I have not found an option for it that works.

Am I missing something obvious, or do I have to do this in a more complicated manner?

(if I've missed a duplicate of this question, please let me know, I was not able to find the specific circumstance I am looking to accomplish discussed)

code:

```
tooltip : {
    shared          : true,
    useHTML         : true,
    headerFormat    : 
         '<table class="tip"><caption>Group {point.key}</caption>'
        +'<tbody>', 
    pointFormat     : 
         '<tr><th style="color: {series.color}">{series.name}: </th>'
        +'<td style="text-align: right">${point.y}</td></tr>',
    footerFormat    : 
         '<tr><th>Total: </th>'
        +'<td style="text-align:right"><b>${???}</b></td></tr>'
        +'</tbody></table>'
}
```

- Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/AeLFZ/

Comment: You mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/AeLFZ/9/

Comment: Something like that, but I need to retain the 'shared:true' and the 'useHTML:true', and I need it to be part of the footerFormat rather than the pointFormat.

Comment: Another solution: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/AeLFZ/11/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`footerFormat` does not have acces to `${point}`.  See [footerFormat documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.footerFormat).

If you want to have a table with each point using `shared:true` you need to use the formatter function like this:

```
formatter: function() {
            var tooltip='<table class="tip"><caption>Group '+this.x+'</caption><tbody>';
            //loop each point in this.points
            $.each(this.points,function(i,point){
                tooltip+='<tr><th style="color: '+point.series.color+'">'+point.series.name+': </th>'
                      + '<td style="text-align: right">'+point.y+'</td></tr>'
            });
            tooltip+='<tr><th>Total: </th>'
            +'<td style="text-align:right"><b>'+this.points[0].total+'</b></td></tr>'
            +'</tbody></table>';
            return tooltip;
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AeLFZ/10/

Comment: Thanks. It seems quite silly to not have access to such information in any part of the tooltip, and to not have ready access to stack totals from any point, when there's such a nice set up with the header, point, and footer format properties. It feels like a step backward to use the formatter and run a loop...

Comment: This goes within the `tooltip:` object in the high charts API.  Also use `shared: true,` and `useHTML: true,` in the same object.

Answer (score 7):

Here is my approach using footerFormat and its 100% working

```
tooltip: {
     shared: true,
     headerFormat: '<b>Week {point.x}</b><br>',
     pointFormat: '<b>{series.name}:</b> {point.y} ( {point.percentage:.0f}% )<br>',
     footerFormat: '<b>Total:  {point.total} </b>'
},
```

[image]